# Statistics on sharepoint use worldwide?

Tags: statistics

Does anyone know if there are any statistics out there for how many companies use SharePoint world wide?  I did a quick search but couldn't find anything....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good timing.  According to a post from Mary Jo Foley today, it was 17,000 customers and 100 million SharePoint users in 2009, and they have added 20,000 users a day ever since:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-were-adding-20000-new-sharepoint-users-a-day/9011